# Proof on random variable sum of the numbers on the two dice

Tags: probability

Consider the experiment

"A current die is rolled two consecutive times" and the random variable

$$X:\text{"The sum of the results of the dice on the upper die faces"}$$

Note that in this case the sigma-algebra is given by $\mathcal P(\Omega)$ from where $\Omega=\{(a, b):a, b\in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}\}$ so for any probability function $(\Omega, \mathcal P(\Omega), P)$ It is a probability space.

I want to show that $X$ is a random variable over $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$, so I try to define the aplication $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by

\begin{equation*}
X(\omega)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\text{What here?}\\ 
m+m \hspace{0.5cm} \text{if} \hspace{0.5cm} \omega=(m, n) \in \Omega
 \\ 
\text{What here?}
\end{matrix}\right.\end{equation*}

Maybe this function can be completed in parts, but it is not very clear to me what other values this function could take, any help to complete this function?

Now, how can I guarantee that this is a random variable, because apparently

$$X^{-1}((-\infty, x]) \in \mathcal P(\Omega)$$

But I don't see this clear, any help to make this a little clearer?

Finally, the distribution function should be

$$F_{X}(x)=P(X\leq x)=P(X^{-1}(-\infty, x])$$

But of course, I had a hard time defining this function because I'm not sure what the inverse image of this Borelean looks like.

I have been able to obtain some values for the function

[image: Table of values]

And from there make a small graph, but I don't know if this is the best way to express the distribution function, is there a better way to write this function?

Comment: For the definition of $X$, it should be $m + n$ on the RHS, and there are no other cases. What would the other cases be? You have already defined the random variable for every possible outcome. For $X^{-1}((-\infty, x]) \in \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$, you could verify this by cases for each choice of $x$, but this is overkill -- the preimage of any set under $X$ must, by definition, be a set in $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$. The definitions and properties you are attempting to verify only become significant when the probability space is infinite.

Comment: @legionwhale That is to say that, using the definition of inverse image and set of parts, I can easily guarantee that it is a random variable?

Comment: The measurability requirements are only non-trivial in the infinite case, where we need assurances about integrability. In the finite case, everything is clearly integrable, so all of these conditions can be ignored. "...using the definition of inverse image and set of parts" How else would you try to prove what you wanted to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Partial answer*

These values as a stepwise function is

$$f_X(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1{36}\cdot (6-|7-x|) \quad \forall \ x\in\{2,...,12\} \\ 0, \quad \textrm{elsewhere} \end{cases}$$

You see that the function is symmetric around $x=7$.